# JavaScript - Click an image, then click a div, then move image to div

Tags: javascript, image, events, scope

I want to click on an image, then click on a destination div, then move the image to where the destination div is.

i is the id of the image, there are 6 images with id's 1 to 6 that correspond to i.

one_c is the destination div.

All working now.. Thanks.

```
function move_c(i) {
  this.image = i;
  one_c.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_one_c(image)');
}

function move_to_one_c(i) {
  document.getElementById("one_c").appendChild(document.getElementById(i));
  document.getElementById(i).style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

[See it in action here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/harleycalvert/scgame/blob/scgame/index.html)

Comment: where is html, use fiddler to make the question clear

Answer (score 2):

Create DOM element using HTML DOM createElement and append the img using appendChild() method and assign the source ID to it. I've prepared a sample plunker here. This may help you to start with it.

```
var i= Obj.id;
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "picture1.jpg");
elem.setAttribute("height", "100");
elem.setAttribute("width", "100");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
document.getElementById(i).appendChild(elem);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Whan4TR3hakfx0cBXofI?p=preview

Comment: its for a game and the image is a piece, so the image needs to be able to be moved again and again, maybe I can use this...

Comment: Yeah . It's just a sample . But the whole idea is to append and remove child as you need

Comment: I'm going to use the 

document.getElementById(i).appendChild(elem); 

bit, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample, it does more or less what you asked and shows how you can do it without needing ID attributes on the images.

```js
var otherDiv = document.getElementById('other');
var one_c = document.getElementById('one_c');

var imgs = otherDiv.querySelectorAll('img');
for (var i=0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('click', move_c);
}

one_c.addEventListener('click', move_to_one_c);

function move_c(e) {
  this.setAttribute('data-selected', true);
  this.className += ' picked';
}

function move_to_one_c(e) {
  var imgs = otherDiv.querySelectorAll('img[data-selected=true]');
  for (var i=0, img; img = imgs[i]; i++) {
    img.setAttribute('data-selected', false);
    img.className = img.className.replace(' picked', '');
    img.removeEventListener('click', move_c);
    one_c.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

```css
#other {
  height: 125px;
  width: 500px;
  background: navy;
}
#one_c {
  height: 125px;
  width: 500px;
  background: silver;
}
.picked {
  border: 2px outset;
}
```

```html
<div id='other'>
  <img src='http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/129/cache/black-skimmer_12923_160x120.jpg'>
  <img src='http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/126/cache/blue-eyed-ostrich_12606_160x120.jpg'>
</div>
<div id='one_c'></div>
```